# Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, uninstall

i have ubuntu 12.04 and i would like to remove it and reinstall it with ubuntu 12.10 but i also dual boot it with windows 7. all i want to do is remove the ubuntu 12.04 so then i can install 12.10. any ideas? i dont want anything complicated... isnt there like a remove feature inside of ubuntu? like windows you can just uninstall it? is there no button to uninstall ubuntu in ubuntu? its just because my 12.04 wont connect to servers porperally and upgrade so im trying ubuntu 12.10.
thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Just download Ubuntu 12.10 and run it. After the first (or second) screen in Ubiquity (the installer), there will be an option saying: Upgrade ubuntu 12.04 with ubuntu 12.10. Select that, and you should be good to go!

[image]